# How can I set the right parameters of dataset.Table[0].Compute(string expression,string filter)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can not get the right result from the following code block:

```
object ob = ds_bug.Tables[0].Compute("Count(id)",str_vertical +"= '"+"' and "+str_horizontal+" = '"+first_row.Cells[j].Text.ToString()+"'");// ds_bug has been filled some data.
```

str_vertical and str_horizontal are two  fields from the ds_bug.Tables[0], and I can see their values are right too when I  debug the code.

Is there any problem I set the filter with a string like " a = '##' and b = '##' "  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should split the method call and the initialization of the expression and the filter, that makes it clearer:

I assume that `first_row.Cells[j].Text.ToString()` is a static value that you've queried previously, so you can declare it like:

```
String firstRowCellsJText = first_row.Cells[j].Text.ToString();
String expression="Count(id)";
String filter = "str_vertical=str_horizontal + " + firstRowCellsJText;
object ob = s_bug.Tables[0].Compute(expression,filter);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it now. I have not  much experience of programming. Your code block makes it much clearer ,and  I will program like that .